# Windows phone 7 add items asynchronously to stackpanel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, stackpanel

I'm wondering if it is possible add children asynchronously to stackpanel (or any other element). It seems that all items are rendered at once.

it doesn't matter if i use background worker or dispatcher. Always the result is the same - when all items have been added then they are shown.

What i would like to have is something like this:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
    foreach (var item in items.Skip(x).Take(pageSize))
    {
        // when this row is executed new item should be visible
        ItemsList.Children.Add(new _ListItem(item));
    }
});
```

regards
max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This snippet adds new TextBlock into stackPanel every 500 ms without freezing UI. Item is visible in UI right after it has been added:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => {
                foreach (int item in Enumerable.Range(1,50)) {
                  Thread.Sleep(500);//simulate some calculations here
                  int item1 = item;
                  Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
                      stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock(){Text = "Text "+item1});
                  });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class to store the items you want to display. That class implements the [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) interface, which will allow it to update the UI as items are added and removed.

Here are some more details about [binding to an ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx) and [updating the UI as items are added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677757/have-an-observablecollection-update-the-ui-as-elements-get-added-in) (See this [demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XHHV2udPhmo)).

Also you may need to add/remove items using the [Dispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677757/have-an-observablecollection-update-the-ui-as-elements-get-added-in).